# Can 'far' be used as a noun

Tags: parts-of-speech

***He comes from far.***

Is this a correct sentence? The confusion is that '**far**' follows a preposition (*from*), which means that '**far**' is being used as a noun. Can '***far***' be used as a noun? Standard dictionaries list ***'far'*** as an adjective/adverb.

Comment: "He comes from afar" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I would take this as a shortened form of something like:

> - He comes from far away.
> - He comes from a far place.

Such shortening is common in English, particularly in informal usage, and it sometimes uses words in roles that they do not normally have. I would not call this wrong.